# Too many mongod processes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We have test server with 3 different node.js apps running on it. Each application is using the same MongoDB database test instance of which also runs on the same server. So at any given moment of time we have at most 3 different open connections to mongodb server.

The issue is that after each code deployment (which basically is: killing currently running process, code update and starting new process) i see new process(thread of a single proccess) on server which is shown in htop as `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf`. Thus once in awhile we have to restart the test server because there are too many not used threads like that and it makes the mongod process take all the RAM.

I am not sure why is this happening and looking for solution to fix this issue.

My assumption is that if we simply kill the node.js proccess the connection (and therefore the thread related to this connection) somehow stays alive and therefore instead of killing nodejs process, we should gracefully shut it down with closing the DB connection.

Comment: Indeed mongod is the database and not a client. Without knowing how node.js works I doubt that there should be any mongo process either. Mongo will be the actual mongo console, a client. So you should just see your node.js instances, which internally have somewhere a node.js mongodb client. But I don't know how node.js is doing it's internal stuff.  
In general it shouldn't matter how you close your apps (graceful or not) as child processes should be terminated as well. But a graceful shutdown is normally the way to go.

Comment: @philnate I sure know difference between `mongod` and `mongo`. But i don't find any logic why i see so many processes in htop related to mongodb. Those are taking all the memory and after rebooting server disappear. Must be some mongo related zombie processes.

Comment: I would suspect that your setup is calling mongod somehow this way (manual startup). But as it's using a file this is a bit strange. Please check if there's an IP defined within /etc/mongodb.conf. Do your apps always connect to the same IP (mongod) or is the IP dynamically defined? If those processes would be zombies you should be able to see this with  ps (no resource consumption and Z flag), but I don't know if this would free the port in use so that another one could take over.

Comment: I would say the problem is in your code deployment. Are you using some kind of third party written script here like a make script? `mongod` should not be able to spawned on its own and I cannot see how node.js would do that (it shouldn't), I would say it is something ontop doing this and not cleanly closing the old mongod process

Answer (score 9):

htop is also showing different threads, your mongod isn't started multiple times, which wouldn't be possible with the same config because the port is already in use.

use top or ps aux | grep mongod and you should see just one process.

you can also configure htop not to show those, press F2 > display options > hide userland threads.

Comment: Oh, yes, this is what i meant, sorry for confusing description. However that does not answer why it is running so many threads and takes all the memory. My setup is pretty standard and i haven't seen any complains about this kind of behavior.

Comment: did you have a look at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/#memory-diagnostics ?  we are running mongodb in production and deploy / restart a lot of our apps but haven't run into that issue that we run out of memory and therefore had to restart the machine, seems strange.

Comment: Yes, i read it, not helpful at all. It doesn't explain why memory usage increases significantly over a time. When we restart server and all apps are running the memory used is about 60-70%, after one-two month uptime it goes to 99.9%.

Comment: Same issue here. We have a lot of threads on mongdb -f, and when it gets to certain amount, the process completely freezes and we have to use sigkill :S. Any ideas? Using mongo 2.6.11

Comment: @clopez have you found a way of this? Faced the same issue

Comment: @SviatKuzhelev If I remember correctly, the main problem was lack of ram on the machine.